# RuntimeError: Cannot share client between multiple processes #440

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redis, memcached

I have two nodes of redis elastic cache, I am running two instances under a load balancer, one in the ap-southeast-1a zone and another in the ap-southeast-1b zone. Also nodes are running in different zones also. ap-southeast-1a and ap-sooutheast-1b, this is the testing environment we have right now. i

Its a ruby 2 and rails 3.2.x e-commerce application.

We are using dalli gem to connect and fetch data from the redis elastic cache, basically dalli acts as redis client for elastic memcache.

The problem what I am facing now is,

For some reason the traffic is moving to the 1b of the ec2 instance which is putting the system into the crash state. But Redis elastic cache seems to be good only 1b seems to be problem.

Here is my config file

```
config file:
defaults:
ttl: 1800
readonly: false
urlencode: false
c_threshold: 10000
compression: true
debug: false
namespace: ""
sessions: true
fragments: true
memory: 128
servers:
- my-test-server:11211
benchmarking: true
raise_errors: true
fast_hash: false
fastest_hash: false

error:
my-test-server:11211 failed (count: 0) RuntimeError: Cannot share client between multiple processes
#
retrying request with new server
Dalli::Server#connect my-test-server:11211
```

Kindly help me out. This issue is been there since long time.

Comment: have you got any solution?